# Javascript onclick button not working on mobile devices in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

JavaScript OnClick event button not working on mobile devices using Jquery.

I researched a lot and tried all the suggestions but still not working!!!

This function works perfectly in desktop !!!

this is a wordpress site.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="smt">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <input id="noc" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Enter Number of Components"  />
                    <input id="nos" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Enter Number of Suppliers"  />
                </div>
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <button class="btn" id="calculateBtn">Calculate Savings*</button>
                </div>
                 <div class="right-column">
                <h4><b>Hours Saved: <span id="ts" class="result"></span></b></h4>
                <h4><b>Amount Saved: <span id="as" class="result"></span></b></h4>
               </div >
            </div>
        <div class=""></div>
           </div>  
           </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script>

 $(window).load(function() { 
    $('#calculateBtn').on('click touchstart', function() {

    var noc = $("#noc").val();
    var nos = $("#nos").val();
    if (noc == "" && nos == "") {
      //  alert("Please Enter the values in the fields");
    } else {
        var crfq1 = 1;
        var crto1 = 3;
        var ana1 = 2;
        var cpo1 = 2;
        var tt = ((noc * nos) * (crfq1 + crto1 + ana1 + cpo1)) / 60;
        var crfq2 = 1;
        var crto2 = 0;
        var ana2 = 1;
        var cpo2 = 0.5;
        var tt2 = (((noc * nos) + 1) * (ana2 + cpo2)) / 60;
        var tts = tt - tt2;
        var totalAmountSaving = tts * 30;
        $("#ts").text(tts.toFixed(2));
        $("#as").text('$' + totalAmountSaving.toFixed(2));
        var noc = $("#noc").val("").focus();
        var nos = $("#nos").val("");
    }

    });
 });


</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide us with more information than just "not working". Whats not working? Does it give an error? If nothing is happening, have you debugged your code to find out which part is not working? Also, add your code in a working code snippet/jsfiddle/codepen, so we can see whats happening.

Comment: can you try this way  $(document).on('click touchstart', '#calculateBtn',function() {


also mention which version of jquery you are using

Comment: hi @FluffyKitten thanks. here is link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/akwa770/sekn443d/1/

Comment: You haven't told us what "not working" means. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: It does not respond. it's not even entered the function. i realy don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the tap event: https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_tap.asp

Comment: load jquery mobile in your code and this should work

Comment: The event working and all the fields are recognized by the device. but not the text input. when I insert some data to the fields the device consider it as empty.